# How can I, on some global keystroke, paste some text to current active application in linux with Python or C++

Tags: c++, python, linux, xserver

I want to write app, which will work like a daemon and on some global keystroke paste some text to current active application (text editor, browser, jabber client) I think i will need to use some low level xserver api. How i can do this with Python or C++ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [xmacroplay utility from xmacro](http://xmacro.sourceforge.net/) to do this under X windows I think.  Either use it directly - send it commands to standard input using the subprocess module, or read the source code and find out how it does it!  I don't think there are python bindings for it.

From the xmacroplay website

```
xmacroplay:
Reads lines from the standard input. It can understand the following lines:

Delay [sec]     - delays the program with [sec] secundums
ButtonPress [n] - sends a ButtonPress event with button [n]
          this emulates the pressing of the mouse button [n]
ButtonRelease [n]   - sends a ButtonRelease event with button [n]
          this emulates the releasing of the mouse button [n]
... snip lots more ...
```

This is probably the command you are interested in

```
String [max. 1024 long string]
        - Sends the string as single characters converted to
          KeyPress and KeyRelease events based on a
          character table in chartbl.h (currently only
          Latin1 is used...)
```

There is also [Xnee](http://www.gnu.org/software/xnee/) which does a similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

#### Probably you want to hack [xmon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmon/)...

---

AFAIK there is no easy way to hook the X protocol. You will need to do "deep packet inspection", which would be fairly easy in the application event loop but not so easy, as you want, "like a daemon", or on "global keystroke[s]".

So, I know this is really brute force and ignorance, but I think you will have to wrap the X server by starting it on a non-standard port or publishing an environment variable, just like you were using something like an SSH tunnel to forward an X server connection.

There is an X protocol monitor called Xmon for which source is available. It might be a good starting point.